# Request Web Service to get JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, web-services

I need to hit web service URL which is giving me JSON object and use basic authentication. How can I perform the the same in JavaScript. I am using the code below, but nothing happens on browser.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
<script>

function send_with_ajax()

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open("GET", 'url of service', true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    httpRequest.send();

    httpRequest.onload= function() { 
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4)
        {
            var _tempRecommendations = httpRequest.responseXML;
            window.alert(httpRequest.response);
            window.alert(httpRequest.responseText);
            window.alert(_tempRecommendations);
        }
    };  
};

</script>
</head>
<body onload="send_with_ajax()"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Set the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

check jQuery out for this action. It would result in something like

```
    $.get("http://yourRestprovider.com/yourResource",function(data){
    //handle your data 
    },"json");
```

please specify what you mean with basic authentication since I see no approach of authenticating against the server in your code snippet!

Answer (score 0):

(You don't need JQuery for this.)

First make sure the inner function is running at all, so try setting the function to `onreadystatechange` instead of `onload`.

As for authentication: If your domain (the thing that replaces 'url of service') has the same origin as the page the script is in, and you're already doing some sort of authentication which stores a login session cookie, you don't need to do anything else.

Comment: hi if i use onreadystatechange i am getting alerts : response and responseText (nothing on alert) and  _tempRecommendations is null how can i sort this out.

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear, what's the observed behavior? _tempRecommendations is null, I got that. Did you see any alerts? Empty alerts? But more importantly, do the domains match? Are you testing the html file on your local computer?

Answer (score -1):

Hi i am using below code : after that it just shows loading on browser.

```
<html><head>
<title>Hello World</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a1/jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function send_with_ajax()
{

        $.ajax  
        ({  
          type: "GET",  
          url: "https://url with params",  
          dataType: 'json',  
          async: false,  
          username: 'abc',  
          password: 'def',  
          data: '{ "comment" }',  
          success: function (){  
            alert('Success!');   
          }  
        });  
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload="send_with_ajax()"></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code Updated, but still not able to get json.